# How to join two result sets in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to join two different result sets in mySQL to be displayed side by. For example lets say I have a result set #1 as follow -

```
NAME    PHONE
ABC     123
DEF     456
GHI     789
```

Result Set # 2 -

```
MAIL ID        WEBSITE
JKL@JKL.COM    WWW.JKL.COM
MNO@MNO.COM    WWW.MNO.COM
PQR@PQR.COM    WWW.PQR.COM
```

Now what I want is these two result to be displayed side by side in a single result set without any relation.

```
NAME    PHONE    MAIL ID        WEBSITE
ABC     123      JKL@JKL.COM    WWW.JKL.COM
DEF     456      MNO@MNO.COM    WWW.MNO.COM
GHI     789      PQR@PQR.COM    WWW.PQR.COM
```

How should I do it?

Comment: How do you know that 'ABC' owns email 'JKL@JKL.COM' ?

Comment: must connect the tables with foreign key.

Comment: "*without any relation*"?  But "joining" them implies a relation.  Or are you merely looking to format the presentation for output (in which case this isn't a MySQL question at all, but one for the language from which you are accessing MySQL)?

Comment: these two results are not related any how. I just want the results to be displayed side by side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a join between two tables that don't have an id.  Well, you can't really do this.  Tables in SQL are not ordered, so you need a keys to link them.

You can do something.  And, if you are lucky, it will work.  The following adds a row number to each table and then joins on that:

```
select t1.name, t1.phone, t2.mail, t2.website
from (select t1.*, @r1 as r1, @r1 := @r1 + 1
      from t1 cross join (select @r1 := 0)
     ) r1 join
     (select t2.*, @r2 as r2, @r1 := @r2 + 1
      from t2 cross join (select @r2 := 0)
     ) r2
     on t1.r1 = t2.r2
```

I must emphasize that this is *not* guaranteed to work.  You really need a proper join key between the tables.  However, it might work.